# Attempt to launch an activity (google.com) outside my app

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button googleBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.googleBtn);
        googleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String google = "https://www.google.com";
                Uri webaddress = Uri.parse(google);

                Intent gotoGoogle = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webaddress);
                if(gotoGoogle.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(gotoGoogle);
                }
                

            }
        });
    }
}
```

With this code I'm trying to launch google.com when I push the google button, but nothing happens when I do. I don't see the toast message either so the if statement seems to be always false.

I've tried using a different virtual device and emulator, looked for anything wrong in the code. I can't seem to pin down where the issue lies. I'm a beginner with android-studio and Java if you couldn't tell already.

Comment: Also ive checked the id of the button and im sure its googleBtn so that cant be the issue. ive also run the code with the toast message outside the if statement that it is in now, that would give me the message Google button clicked when the button was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button googleBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.googleBtn);
    googleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           String url = "https://www.google.com/";
           Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
           i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
           startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! ive been trying to fix it for two days this really helps.